# How to identify number of Duplicate elements in multi array

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I had a multi array as follows

```
[
    {Name: "test1", Role: "Role1", Product: "Product4", Rate: 146, Rate_Override: 0},
    {Name: "test2", Role: "Role1", Product: "Product1", Rate: 147, Rate_Override: 0},
    {Name: "test3", Role: "Role1", Product: "Product1", Rate: 148, Rate_Override: 0},
    {Name: "test4", Role: "Role2", Product: "Product1", Rate: 149, Rate_Override: 0},
    {Name: "test5", Role: "Role3", Product: "Product2", Rate: 146, Rate_Override: 0},
    {Name: "test6", Role: "Role1", Product: "Product1", Rate: 146, Rate_Override: 0},
]
```

How can i get number of duplicate records that matches Role and Product ?

The combination of `Role1 and Product4 is 1`

The combination of `Role1 and Product1 is 3`

The combination of `Role2 and Product1 is 1`

The combination of `Role3 and Product2 is 1`

Comment: What you have tried till now ?

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```js
const a = [
    {Name: "test1", Role: "Role1", Product: "Product4",Rate: 146,Rate_Override: 0},
    {Name: "test2", Role: "Role1", Product: "Product1",Rate: 147,Rate_Override: 0},
    {Name: "test3", Role: "Role1", Product: "Product1",Rate: 148,Rate_Override: 0},
    {Name: "test4", Role: "Role2", Product: "Product1",Rate: 149,Rate_Override: 0},
    {Name: "test5", Role: "Role3", Product: "Product2",Rate: 146,Rate_Override: 0},
    {Name: "test6", Role: "Role1", Product: "Product1",Rate: 146,Rate_Override: 0}
]


const match = (role, product) => a.reduce((res, o) => res + (o.Role == role && o.Product == product), 0);

console.log(match('Role1', 'Product4')); // 1
console.log(match('Role1', 'Product1')); // 3
console.log(match('Role2', 'Product1')); // 1
console.log(match('Role3', 'Product2')); // 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and count the wanted combinated properties.

```js
var array = [{ Name: "test1", Role: "Role1", Product: "Product4",Rate: 146,Rate_Override: 0 }, { Name: "test2", Role: "Role1", Product: "Product1",Rate: 147,Rate_Override: 0 }, { Name: "test3", Role: "Role1", Product: "Product1",Rate: 148,Rate_Override: 0 }, { Name: "test4", Role: "Role2", Product: "Product1",Rate: 149,Rate_Override: 0 }, { Name: "test5", Role: "Role3", Product: "Product2",Rate: 146,Rate_Override: 0 }, { Name: "test6", Role: "Role1", Product: "Product1",Rate: 146,Rate_Override: 0 }],
    keys = ['Role', 'Product'],
    count = Array.from(
        array.reduce(
            (m, o) =>
                (k => m.set(k, (m.get(k) || 0) + 1))
                (keys.map(k => o[k]).join('|')),
            new Map
        ),
        ([k, v]) => k.split('|').concat(v)
    );

console.log(count);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```